# CSS Styling for scala js bootstrap Modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, scala.js

I am trying to use scalajs in one of our application. I needed a bootstrap modal dialog box, for which I am using https://github.com/Karasiq/scalajs-bootstrap

I would like to display the some dynamic content on it and the content can be huge sometimes. The problem is the data goes out of modal.

I see that html bootstrap css modal (http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp) has lot of CSS options/properties to set styles like -

1. `overflow: auto;` etc.
2. `modal-dialog modal-lg` for choosing larger modal

But I don't see any such option in scala js. Any help appreciated.

```
Modal()
.withTitle(modalTitle)
.withBody(content).withButtons(
Modal.button("Apply", Modal.dismiss),
Modal.closeButton("Close")).show()
```

Comment: Hmm.  I believe the issue here isn't Scala.js per se, it's the scalajs-bootstrap library.  What you want is to be able to define additional classes on the Modal div -- setting `modal-lg` to get the larger modal, and probably your own class that matches your CSS file for the overflow -- but the library appears to be too locked-down to do that easily.  (It could be worked around, but it would require hacking it.)  I'd recommend writing to the author about it, or maybe raising an issue in the GitHub repository...

Comment: That's correct @JustinduCoeur. The issue is with scalajs-bootstrap library. I can own a CSS class with all the custom CSS properties but, at this point of time  I don't see how I can pass that information to the library.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think there's a great answer here.  Personally, I'd probably fork the library, add the ability to add classes to the Modal, and offer that as a PR for the upstream library...

Comment: It would we wonderful, if you could do that. Thanks in Advance. @JustinduCoeur

Comment: Um, no, sorry -- the above means that *if* I had this problem, that's what I would do.  (Sorry -- the English subjunctive can be confusing.)  I'm recommending that you do so.  I'm flat-out busy (and away for most of the next month), so I don't have any cycles to work on this.  If you can't do it yourself, I'd strongly recommend opening an issue on the library in GitHub...

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding. Indeed, English can be confusing at times :) . We have opened an issue asking for suggestion. Let's wait for the response and then if they recommend I can add the this feature and create a PR.